# Iterating Two Maps Inside A Resource using for_each

Tags: foreach, terraform, srv-record

I'm Trying to create azure SRV record based on some condition, for this multiple target is needed for a single SRV record. If I iterate inside dynamic each.key and each.value is referring the key value outside the dynamic block. is there a way to iterate this record block for required number of time. Also the count is not supported in record block. Could there be any other ways to achieve this without loop also fine.

NOTE: this is a pseudo code for reference.

```
resource "azurerm_dns_srv_record" "srv_dns_record" {
  for_each            = { for key, value in var.clusters : key => value if some condition }
  name                = name
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.cluster_dns_zone[each.key].name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  ttl                 = 60

  dynamic "record" {
    for_each = var.targets
    content {
      priority = 1
      weight   = 5
      port     = 443
      target   = each.key
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `var.clusters`? What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: var.clusters don't have the targets , its in a separate variable var.targets
```target   = each.key``` here is the error each.key is taking values from ```var.clusters``` but required from ```var.target```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over `var.targets` in side a dynamic block, it should be:

```
target   = record.key
```

Answer (score 2):

from the [docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks)

> The iterator argument (optional) sets the name of a temporary variable that represents the current element of the complex value. If omitted, the name of the variable defaults to the label of the dynamic block ("setting" in the example above).

so to refer to the value of the iterated field in the dynamic block you should use the label of the block not the `each` word

```
resource "azurerm_dns_srv_record" "srv_dns_record" {
  for_each            = { for key, value in var.clusters : key => value if some condition }
  name                = name
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.cluster_dns_zone[each.key].name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  ttl                 = 60

  dynamic "record" {
    for_each = var.targets
    content {
      priority = 1
      weight   = 5
      port     = 443
      target   = record.key
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well, In should have read that properly.